# Scalable design for vsphere 4.1

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vcenter

We have procured 
1x C7000 Chasis 
2xVirtual connect 
2x9124 FC switch
5xBL460 G6 with Dual port HBA
1 NetApp Filer(FC) with Dual controller Active/Active
1xNetApp filer(SATA) with Single controller

We need to deploy scalable design with Vsphere 4.1

We will be using 3 blade for VMWARE Vsphere4.1 and 2 blade as Physical for other application
There will be 6 VMs including Vcenter

How should be the Virtual Connect connection to cater both Physical and Virtual environment within the same chasis

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out a lot of information (specifically about your downstream LAN ports or any intermediary SAN switches) but let's break it down into chunks.

The easy one is the SAN, simply run however many ports you like from your 9124s into your NetApp, I'd be tempted to run them as point-to-point links if you have no intermediary switches and use NPIV rather than run them as ISL trunks (not sure if the NetApp can deal with ISL anyway). So you'll create two SAN networks, one per host port and just map them stright through - no need for VSANs/Zones etc.

The LAN question is a little trickier, and can't cover your physical servers as you've provided no network requirements - assuming your downstream ports are switches that can handle trunks then what I'd do for your ESX boxes is split each flexNIC into two vNICs, one at 2Gbps and the other at 8Gbsps, do this for both adapters giving your hosts 4 vNICs each, create a management/vMotion vswitch using both 2Gb vNICs and a VM traffic vSwitch with the both 8Gb vNICs. Create two VC networks, one for the two management/vmotion vNICs and one for the VM traffic vNICs, drop your real trunk ports into their port groups and you're away.

For both LAN and SAN use the hardware MACs/WWNs, no point using the pooled ones in this situation. Oh and let your VC do the VLAN tagging (unless you plan on separate trunks for both functions in which case just let the tags go through to ESX to break out).

This'll be fine for the ESX and probably good enough from the SAN perspectice for you physicals but as I said you've given us nothing to work on for the physical LAN ports.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty awful line of questioning. Let's get started.

1. What do you even mean by "scalable?" There's all kinds of scalability. You need to clarify exactly what you're trying to scale, and what imposes scalability bottlenecks on your application.
2. There's no such thing as a one-size-fits-all scalable design. There is literally nothing we can tell you about making your applications scale if we have no idea what you're trying to do with the cluster. Even within the same application, different use cases have vastly different performance requirements. We can't guess what you need to stay scalable. You have to tell us. If you're not sure what numbers you're looking for, VMware Capacity Planner should help you. Install it on your physical servers, let it cook a week, and then come back to us.
3. What are you even accomplishing by running five virtual machines (excluding vCenter) on three physical systems? There's countless DR benefits to virtualization, but if you don't have a broader consolidation project it sounds like you could save a ton of money by just doing boot-from-SAN on all of your physical hosts.
4. You definitely don't want to run your cluster VMs within the same blade chassis, especially if you're relying on HA to keep things available in the event of a host failure -- your chassis introduces a single point of failure on your entire environment. If you only have one blade chassis, don't use blades for this. Buy 1U or 2U pizzaboxes. You'll be much happier.
5. I've never seen a SAN that couldn't keep up with VMware. I have, however, seen plenty of arrays within the SAN that can't, because the administrators didn't properly understand the I/O profiles of their application or how that affects the design of a physical disk array.

If you're in over your head, and you sound like you are because you don't know the questions you should be asking, you should really bring in a consultant or at least a VAR to help get you up and running. Virtualization without the expertise to configure or manage it will be a complete disaster for your organization.